# Delphi DBEdit OnExit primary key validation

Tags: database, delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am using Delphi 10.4, when connecting a DBEdit to a table from a database which contains a primary key (eg: student_num). What I want to do is to perform a search on the key the user types in that DBEdit when the user exits or moves to the next DBEdit and not after filling all the fields then hitting a submit button.

Can someone help me with that?
Much gratitude.

I used DBEditChange, but that didn't work as expected. The code I'm trying to write should show a message in case the entered key already exists in the database, immediately after exiting DBEdit field.

Comment: Use OnExit instead. It fires as soon as focus is removed from the DBEdit. Note that you cannot search the same table you've connected to the DBEdit, so you'll have to have a second copy of the table or query open to use to check for dupes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Can you be more specific please ?!

Comment: More specific about what, exactly?

Comment: About where to use OnExit or basically how it works, u see i never used it before and i couldn't find enough information on how to use it

Comment: You use OnExit on the table attached to the DBEdit, just like you did when you tried OnChange. It does exactly what it says - it is fired when the user exits the DBEdit. You use it by clicking on the table or query, switch to the Events tab in the Object Inspector, and double-click on the OnExit event, which will create the event handler stub method in the code and position the edit cursor within that method.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will continue with tomorrow I'm starting to understand it, thank you again